# How to prevent horizontal scroll?

Tags: html, css

Currently my code looks like this

```css
body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #ABA49F;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif
}
.header_bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    z-index: 1000 !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.506);
    height: 22px;
    padding: 7px 40px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #212121 9%, #181818 100%);
    border-bottom: 2px solid #606060;
}
.header_content {
    width: 50%;
    margin: left;
}
.header_content li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.title li a {
    color: #ffc900 !important;
}
.header_content li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
.header_content a:hover {
    color: #ffc900;
}
.sidebar_frame {
    z-index: 111;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:50px;
    background:#000;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar_frame">aaaa</div>
<div class="header_bar">
    <div class="header_content">
        <div class="title">
            <li><a href=""><b>Farm</b></a>
            </li>
        </div>
        <li><a href="">New farm</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">aaaa</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">aaaa</a>
        </li>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to make a sidebar with 100% height. I have no idea why the sidebar without z-index is on top of the menu and also why is there some random scrollable space on the pages horizontal axis?

Removing the sidebar cleans the scrollable space.

Comment: are you talking about the horizontal scrolling that is going on?

Comment: Yes im talking about that

Comment: scrolling is caused by `.header_bar` having 80px side padding with a width of 100% - try adding `box-sizing:border-box`, and add `position:relative` to it as well - z-index only applies to positioned elements.  You have also set 2 heights on it

Comment: Thanks that fixed the scroll issue but the z-index issue is still there. any thoughs?

Comment: did you try adding `position:relative` to `.header_bar`?

Comment: @alvarocarvajalnakosmai you can change the `z-index` of `.sidebar_frame` to `-1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sidebar is overlapping the menu because `position: absolute` elements [are removed from the normal flow of the document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning). This means that the header is positioning itself without regard for the sidebar.

**To fix the overlap:**

Give a `left-margin` to `.header_bar` that is the same width of the sidebar. This accommodates space for the side bar.

**To fix the scrolling issue:**

- Remove the left and right padding from your `.header_bar` and apply it as left padding to the `.title`
- Remove the 100% width of the `.header_bar`

**A few small improvements:**

- Remove the `<li>` and apply the styles directly to the a elements
- Remove or increase the width of `.header_content`
- Remove `margin: left` which does not exist
- Place `.title a` after the other a links properties in the CSS. When property values conflict, the last property declared is the winner. [This eliminates the need for `!important`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css)
- Remove all z-index properties; they are no longer required.

Put that all together and you get this example:

```css
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #ABA49F;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif
}
.header_bar {
  height: 45px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.506);
  height: 22px;
  padding: 7px 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #212121 9%, #181818 100%);
  border-bottom: 2px solid #606060;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.header_content .title {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
.header_content a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 30px;
  float: left;
}
.title a {
  color: #ffc900;
}
.header_content a:hover {
  color: #ffc900;
}
.sidebar_frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
  <div class="sidebar_frame">aaaa</div>
  <div class="header_bar">
    <div class="header_content">
      <div class="title">
        <a href=""><b>Farm</b></a>            
      </div>
      <a href="">New farm</a>          
      <a href="">aaaa</a>          
      <a href="">aaaa</a>          
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution to your problem: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ky871eva/2/). You will need to remove the horizontal padding assigned to `.header_bar` and change the `z-index` of `.sidebar_frame` to `-1`.